# How to get dbcontext in the library without knowing the class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am connecting dbcontext as usual

```
services.AddDbContext<EntityContext>()
```

In the library I need to get this context, but I do not know the class through which DbContext is implemented

This one doesn't work:

```
public class SomeService
{
    public SomeService(DbContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you can look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Comment: Generic type argument with type constraint?

Comment: Hard to imagine a service that says: "give me whichever concrete context type DI has for me. I'll see what I can do with it." Practically, it can only do stuff with the context's meta data. Is that what you mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some of the [`AddDbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions-adddbcontext-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime)) overloads which allow you to specify both base service and implementation service types. The method registers both types (when they are different) in the DI container, thus allowing resolving both of them in dependent services or `GetService` calls.

In this particular case, you need to replace "as usual"

```cs
services.AddDbContext<EntityContext>()
```

with

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DbContext, EntityContext>();
```

Now injecting the `DbContext` in `SomeService` constructor should work (and actually receive `EntityContext` instance).